# SMTP - несколько получателей при отправке с Gmail, даже скрытая копия не доходит

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

Не получается отправить *на нескольких получателей* письмо с Gmail. Читая [это](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) и [это](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), попробовал оба варианта - добавить скрытую копию при помощи `msg['Bcc'] = bcc_addrs` и список адресов получателей в поле `msg['To'] = to_addr`.
Письмо на одного адресата (без `bcc_addrs`) нормально доходит.  Вот код:

```
from pathlib import Path
def send_mail_with_attach(
        to_addr, mail_subject, bcc_addrs=None,
        mail_body="by Python script",
        files_to_attach=[Path(r"D:\OneDrive\PyCodes\SСHEDULER\tenor_Mister_Bin.gif"), ]
        ):
    # Python code to Send mail with attachments
    # from your Gmail account
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582811/gmail-python-multiple-attachments
    # https://realpython.com/python-send-email/
    # https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/sending-emails-in-python-with-smtp--cms-29975
    # error codes:
    # https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/exchange/mail-flow/test-smtp-with-telnet?view=exchserver-2019

    # libraries to be imported
    import smtplib
    import ssl
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders
    from email.utils import formatdate

    # instance of MIMEMultipart
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    # storing the senders email address
    msg['From'] = user
    # storing the receivers email address
    msg['To'] = to_addr
    # storing the subject
    msg['Subject'] = mail_subject  # "Subject of the Mail"
    msg["Date"] = formatdate(localtime=True)

    if bcc_addrs:
        msg['Bcc'] = bcc_addrs

    # attach the body with the msg instance
    msg.attach(MIMEText(mail_body, 'plain'))  # "Body_of_the_mail"

    try:
        for file in files_to_attach:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            with open(file, "rb") as fh:  # open the file to be sent
                data = fh.read()
            filename = file.name
            part.set_payload(data)
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', f'attachment; filename="{filename}"')
            msg.attach(part)
    except IOError:
        msg = f"Error opening attachment file {file.name}"
        print(msg)
        sys.exit(1)

    # Converts the Multipart msg into a string
    text = msg.as_string()

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:   # creates SMTP session
        s.ehlo()    # Can be omitted
        # start TLS for security
        s.starttls(context=context)
        s.ehlo()    # Can be omitted
        # Authentication
        s.login(user, password)  # "Password_of_the_sender"

        s.set_debuglevel(True)
        # sending the mail
        s.sendmail(user, to_addr, text)
```

Вызываю с  `bcc_addrs` - в почте Gmail показывает что есть адресат скрытой копии, но он ничего не получает.  Основной адресат письмо получает. Сообщения об ошибке вроде нет. Вот начало и хвостик:

```
send: 'mail FROM:<vasilij.kolomiets@gmail.com> size=223180\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.1.0 OK t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.0 OK t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp'
send: 'rcpt TO:<vasilij.kolomiets@outlook.com>\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.1.5 OK t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.5 OK t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp'
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: b'354  Go ahead t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'Go ahead t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp'
data: (354, b'Go ahead t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp')
send: b'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============7632431358522942351=="\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nFrom: vasilij.kolomiets@gmail.com\r\nTo: vasilij.kolomiets@outlook.com\r\nSubject: =?utf-8?b?0L/QuNGB0YzQvNC+IDIgIDEyOjUzICBiY2NfYWRkcnM9J3Zhc2lsaWoua29sb21pZXRzQGdtYWlsLmNvbScgLyBkYXRlIC8gIFVrcg==?=\r\nDate: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 12:53:12 +0200\r\nBcc: vasilij.kolomiets@gmail.com\r\n\r\nUkraine\r\n--===============7632431358522942351==\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nby Python script\r\n--===============7632431358522942351==\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename="tenor_Mister_Bin.gif"\r\n\
```

...

```
===============7632431358522942351==--\r\n.\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.0.0 OK  1611226415 t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.0.0 OK  1611226415 t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp'
data: (250, b'2.0.0 OK  1611226415 t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp')
send: 'QUIT\r\n'
reply: b'221 2.0.0 closing connection t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: b'2.0.0 closing connection t4sm503059lff.260 - gsmtp'
```

Итого вопрос - как же отправить письмо сразу нескольким адресатам.
При указании списка адресов типа: `to_addr = "mail_1@that.com, mail_2@that.com"`, письмо числится в отправленных, все адреса разобраны, но ни один получатель ничего не получает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
sender = 'me@example.com'
recipients = ['john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.com']
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

Используйте список для получателей.

Comment: Да, нашел ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

Comment: Ну как можно было догадаться, что там где значением параметра есть строка, может быть и список строк... )))
Python